# Can I force the app to stay on foreground all the time?

Tags: ios, iphone

I mean to make the app stay in foreground when no-one touches the iPhone? I need the app to stay available to receive remote commands to turn on a camera. It's desirable to dim the screen, but prevent iPhone from locking and putting the app to the background? The device will likely to stay connected to a charger.

Comment: You can't do it programmatically but you can use single app mode either via an MDM policy if it is a dedicated device or through guided access.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [`UIApplication.isIdleTimerDisabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623070-isidletimerdisabled) like this.

> The default value of this property is false. When most apps have no touches as user input for a short period, the system puts the device into a "sleep” state where the screen dims. This is done for the purposes of conserving power. However, apps that don't have user input except for the accelerometer—games, for instance—can, by setting this property to true, disable the “idle timer” to avert system sleep.

```
// This will prevent the app from going to background (automatically by screen dimming etc.)
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true

// Do not forget to reset this after your task is done
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
```